# BIRT Webservice based DataSet : Multi-level SOAP Response

Tags: web-services, birt

I'm not sure to be clear with this title so I'll try to explain it better.

I'm using BIRT to create reports and I'm gonna get my data from a Webservice.
To achieve that, I created my Datasource with no problem, however, when trying to create the corresponding dataset, there was missing fields in the Row/Column mapping screen :/

I used a sample XML response to show BIRT what it's going to use :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns1:recupererDetailsContratsResponse soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="http://webservices.main.gimaweb.itrec.com">
         <recupererDetailsContratsReturn href="#id0"/>
      </ns1:recupererDetailsContratsResponse>
      <multiRef id="id0" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns2:ResponseObject" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns2="urn:MyWS">
         <lieux soapenc:arrayType="ns2:myObject[1]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array">
            <lieux href="#id1"/>
         </lieux>
         <someField1 xsi:type="xsd:string">Data</someField1>
         <someField2 xsi:type="xsd:string">Date</someField2>
      </multiRef>
      <multiRef id="id1" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns3:myObject" xmlns:ns3="urn:MyWS" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <missingField1 xsi:type="xsd:string">Data</missingField1>
         <missingField2 xsi:type="xsd:string">Data</missingField2>
         <missingField3 xsi:type="xsd:string">Data</missingField3>
      </multiRef>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And then, when I reach the column mapping screen, there is none of those 3 field...
The tree only goes to le "lieux" object, but not the missingFields

Does someone ever encountered this kind of problem? Don't hesitate to ask for more information if something isn't clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for the next ones looking for this, here is what I have done.

I created a module on client side to transform the SOAP Response in XML and then used an XML Datasource in BIRT. Not what I planned to do, but it's the only way I found.